# jQuery escape and UTF Contents problems

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, decode

I'm submitting a form with jQuery .. and in order to manage the post() i have to escape() some text area.. 
my jQuery script:

```
    var dataString = 'title=' + escape(title) + '&auth=' + auth + '&mainImage=' + mainImage + '&art_text=' + escape(art_text) + '&language=' + language + '&tags=' + tags + '&Status=' + Status + '&postDate=' + datepicker;
    $.post("./Scripts/adminDoAddPost.php", dataString, function (data) {
        //do something
    });
```

now when i get the data .. i reaches my php script as

[image: text looks like this]

while it should be displayed as من نحن

is there a way to decode the whole string?

Comment: After getting the data in php did you use for example `urldecode($_GET['auth'])`? Or `html_entity_decode($_GET['auth'], null, 'UTF-8');`?

Comment: that alone didn't solve the problem for  some reason .. fixed it with

`html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;", urldecode($_POST['art_text'])), null, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Yes, right; you should mix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `urldecode` and `html_entity_decode` as

```
$str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($_GET['whatever']));
$result = html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');
```